# iPhone app under dev crashes if phone not connected through XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I tried this on a few devices, I have an iOS app that crashes when my phone is not connected via XCode.

Steps I follow:

1) Open XCode Project, connect phone to Mac
2) Launch app through XCode
3) App fully works
4) Unplug cable
5) Click again on app Icon -> crash after spashscreen

Would anyone have any idea where I could look to figure out this problem ? As its only occuring while unplugged, I have no logs.

PS: Also I have submitted this app to the App store (as I didn't notice before) and Apple accepted it. Which means their process didn't even find this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem. It's the way you terminate the debugging process. Just add another step:

1) Open XCode Project, connect phone to Mac

2) Launch app through XCode

3) App fully works

**4) STOP the application (from XCode)**

5) Unplug cable

6) Click again on app Icon -> crash after spashscreen

Comment: ok this fixed it thanks, so then I have two different crashes that are not linked, because the app still crashes after beeing submited to the app store :(

Comment: @xtrimsky: ouch, that other crash is from your code or the way you're compiling it. Check Will's answer to see if you can read crash logs. Also: it might be possible that your app is crashing only on very certain type of devices/iOS-es. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567359/released-app-shows-blank-screen-but-not-in-debugger

Comment: @xtrimsky: in that linked answer check if this applies to your app: are you creating any UIImageViews, UIImages or something similiar in the background thread?

Comment: here is my crashlog, I don't see anything helpful but I'm trying to understand it: http://pastebin.com/4Lhhdiyj

Comment: @xtrimsky:i'm a noob when it comes to crash reports in iOS :) There are some guys here on SO that are really great at interpreting them. You could try posting console log and crash report to SO but make sure to add some problem description also - otherwise all you'll get will be a bunch of downvotes.

Comment: @xtrimsky: did you make a completely clean install? delete your app from iPhone and then try to archive your app and install as IPA with iTunes (as described in link provided above).

Comment: the install was completly clean yes. I've tested on two iphones that weren't used for development.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the logs that were recorded when the app crashed by plugging it back into your Mac, opening Xcode, going to the Organizer (`CMD+SHIFT+2`) and looking at the Console for your device. Hopefully here you should be able to see what's causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, I had a problem like this, somewhere in my hap I had a CFRelease( NULL); and that caused the crash.